# Validation Formula in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column-formula

I have a Formula and i want to ADD this condition :

We can't Choose Closed Status when **[Financial impact]<>"Loss",[Breach Nature]<>"Active"**

This is The Formula where i have to add this Condition on it :

```
=AND(
OR([Financial impact]<>"Loss",Status<>"Closed",
AND([Financial impact]="Loss",Status="Closed",
(NOT(ISBLANK([Receivable booking date]))),
(NOT(ISBLANK([Compensation effective date]))))),
OR(Status<>"Closed",[Breach Nature]<>"Active",
AND(Status="Closed",[Breach Nature]="Active",
NOT(ISBLANK([Impact amount])),
NOT(ISBLANK([Client's notification date])),
NOT(ISBLANK([1st CSSF notification date])),
NOT(ISBLANK([Auditor's notification date])),
NOT(ISBLANK([Rule Breach])),
NOT(ISBLANK([1st NAV in breach])),
NOT(ISBLANK([1st correct NAV])),
[Issue Type]<>"-- Please Select --",
NOT(ISBLANK([Financial impact])))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more condition to outer AND as

```
AND([Financial impact]<>"Loss",[Breach Nature]<>"Active",Status<>"Closed")
```

so your complete query will be

```
=AND(
OR([Financial impact]<>"Loss",Status<>"Closed",
AND([Financial impact]="Loss",Status="Closed",
(NOT(ISBLANK([Receivable booking date]))),
(NOT(ISBLANK([Compensation effective date]))))),
OR(Status<>"Closed",[Breach Nature]<>"Active",
AND(Status="Closed",[Breach Nature]="Active",
NOT(ISBLANK([Impact amount])),
NOT(ISBLANK([Client's notification date])),
NOT(ISBLANK([1st CSSF notification date])),
NOT(ISBLANK([Auditor's notification date])),
NOT(ISBLANK([Rule Breach])),
NOT(ISBLANK([1st NAV in breach])),
NOT(ISBLANK([1st correct NAV])),
[Issue Type]<>"-- Please Select --",
NOT(ISBLANK([Financial impact])))),
AND([Financial impact]<>"Loss",[Breach Nature]<>"Active",Status<>"Closed")
)
```